# Listagg Partition instead of Group By

Tags: sql, oracle

Which is more efficient of the 2, specifically in the case when using Listagg with varchar type data?

```
SELECT department_id AS "Dept.",
       LISTAGG(last_name, '; ') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY hire_date) AS "Employees"
  FROM employees
  GROUP BY department_id
  ORDER BY department_id;
```

OR

```
SELECT department_id AS "Dept.",
       LISTAGG(last_name, '; ') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY hire_date) 
       OVER (PARTITION BY department_id) AS "Employees"
  FROM employees
  ORDER BY department_id;
```

For me, unless I'm only selecting 1/2 columns, I'll always use partition as I don't have to include each column in the 'GROUP BY' clause.

Comment: I think you should examine the explain plans of the  2 queries to know what is the most efficient on YOUR data

Comment: Your two queries are basically different, and the **two output results are different**, too. Why do you want to compare them? One is `aggregate`, one is `analytic`. You should search and read more about them first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both queries do the same amount of work, as each one has to perform a full scan of `EMPLOYEES` sorting the values of `LAST_NAME` within `DEPARTMENT_ID`.

Using the Oracle 'HR' demo schema (where `EMPLOYEES` has 107 rows) and the SQL*Plus [`set autotrace`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/sqpug/tuning-SQL-Plus.html) tool, we can see both perform 7 consistent gets and 1 sort.

```
SQL> set autotrace traceonly explain statistics

SQL> select department_id as "Dept."
  2       , listagg(last_name, '; ') within group(order by hire_date) as "Employees"
  3  from   employees
  4  group  by department_id
  5  order  by department_id;

12 rows selected.

Execution Plan
----------------------------------------------------------
Plan hash value: 2107619104

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation          | Name      | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)| Time     |
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT   |           |    11 |   209 |     4  (25)| 00:00:01 |
|   1 |  SORT GROUP BY     |           |    11 |   209 |     4  (25)| 00:00:01 |
|   2 |   TABLE ACCESS FULL| EMPLOYEES |   107 |  2033 |     3   (0)| 00:00:01 |
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Statistics
----------------------------------------------------------
          0  recursive calls
          0  db block gets
          7  consistent gets
          0  physical reads
          0  redo size
       1605  bytes sent via SQL*Net to client
        608  bytes received via SQL*Net from client
          2  SQL*Net roundtrips to/from client
          1  sorts (memory)
          0  sorts (disk)
         12  rows processed

SQL> select department_id as "Dept."
  2       , listagg(last_name, '; ') within group(order by hire_date) over(partition by department_id) as "Employees"
  3  from   employees
  4  order  by department_id;

107 rows selected.

Execution Plan
----------------------------------------------------------
Plan hash value: 1919783947

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation          | Name      | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)| Time     |
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT   |           |   107 |  2033 |     3   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|   1 |  WINDOW SORT       |           |   107 |  2033 |     3   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|   2 |   TABLE ACCESS FULL| EMPLOYEES |   107 |  2033 |     3   (0)| 00:00:01 |
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Statistics
----------------------------------------------------------
          0  recursive calls
          0  db block gets
          7  consistent gets
          0  physical reads
          0  redo size
       3703  bytes sent via SQL*Net to client
        685  bytes received via SQL*Net from client
          9  SQL*Net roundtrips to/from client
          1  sorts (memory)
          0  sorts (disk)
        107  rows processed
```

There is more network activity for the second query as it returns more rows.

Answer (score 12):

The two queries give different outputs. Using `GROUP BY` will return one row-per-group whilst using `OVER ( PARTITION BY .. )` will return all the rows and duplicate the `LISTAGG` result for each row in the partition.

Use whichever solution is more appropriate for your desired output - but they are not equivalent.

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/aefe9/3)

**Oracle 11g R2 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE employees ( department_id, last_name, hire_date ) AS
SELECT 1, 'AAA', DATE '2018-01-01' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1, 'BBB', DATE '2018-01-02' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1, 'CCC', DATE '2018-01-03' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2, 'DDD', DATE '2018-01-01' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2, 'EEE', DATE '2018-01-02' FROM DUAL;
```

**Query 1**:

```
SELECT department_id AS "Dept.",
       LISTAGG(last_name, '; ') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY hire_date) AS "Employees"
  FROM employees
  GROUP BY department_id
  ORDER BY department_id
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/aefe9/3/0)**:

```
| Dept. |     Employees |
|-------|---------------|
|     1 | AAA; BBB; CCC |
|     2 |      DDD; EEE |
```

**Query 2**:

```
SELECT department_id AS "Dept.",
       LISTAGG(last_name, '; ') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY hire_date) 
       OVER (PARTITION BY department_id) AS "Employees"
  FROM employees
  ORDER BY department_id
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/aefe9/3/1)**:

```
| Dept. |     Employees |
|-------|---------------|
|     1 | AAA; BBB; CCC |
|     1 | AAA; BBB; CCC |
|     1 | AAA; BBB; CCC |
|     2 |      DDD; EEE |
|     2 |      DDD; EEE |
```

Comment: You can use a DISTINCT in the second query to achieve the same results. Somtimes I prefere the second query